Perché si usava "latino" nel senso di "facile" o "chiaro"?
Rileggendo il canto III del Paradiso dantesco, ho ritrovato queste terzine in cui Dante personaggio si rivolge a Piccarda Donati (grassetto mio):

     
Ond'io a lei: "Ne' mirabili aspetti
     
vostri risplende non so che divino
     
che vi trasmuta da' primi concetti: 
     
però non fui a rimembrar festino;
     
ma or m'aiuta ciò che tu mi dici,
     
sì che raffigurar m'è più latino.

Il Grande dizionario della lingua italiana conferma (si vedano i numeri 7 e 10)
che c'era un uso antico dell'aggettivo latino con il significato di chiaro, intelligibile o facile. Mi chiedo, però, da dove derivasse questo senso. Perché latino voleva dire facile o chiaro? Forse per contrapposizione al greco che era considerato come difficile o poco accessibile?

Credo, ma è una risposta provvisoria,  che l'uso di latino nel senso di chiaro, limpido, non sia tanto legato alla contrapposizione con il greco, ma con il volgare.
È da ricordare che allora si poneva il problema del volgare, e del rapporto volgare-latino,  che Dante trattò nel De vulgari eloquentia.
Il latino era la lingua dei dotti e la loro lingua scritta, e in quanto tale più stabile e affidabile, mentre il volgare come lingua parlata o usata in scritti di basso livello (ad esempio commerciali, giuridici), era più mutevole e incerto.
Qui un brano che contiene alcuni passi del Convivio di Dante, tratto dalla voce Latino della Enciclopedia Dantesca Treccani, che può chiarire alcuni aspetti del rapporto di Dante con il latino:

Ad ambito figurato simile rimandano gli usi, tipicamente danteschi, di
Pd III 63 m'aiuta ciò che tu mi dici, / sì che raffigurar m'è più
latino, in cui la voce vale " facile " (ma già Betto Mettefuoco Amore
perché 55 " ègli così latino "; e G. Villani [XI 20] dice di papa
Giovanni XXII che " assai era latino di dare udienza ", cioè " facile
" a darla; il Parodi [Lingua 281] collega questo passo a quello di Cv
II III 1 A più latinamente vedere la sentenza litterale...), e Rime
CXIII 2 la voce vostra sì dolce e latina, ove si tende verso
l'accezione di " limpida ", " chiara ".
La lingua latina. - Il I. è per D. lingua artificialis di fronte al
volgare usuale (Cv I V 14 lo volgare seguita uso, e lo latino arte).
Il pensiero dantesco sul rapporto l.-volgare e sulla maggiore
importanza dell'uno o dell'altro è discusso. In Cv I V 7-14 il l. è
detto sovrano... per nobilità... perché lo latino è perpetuo e non
corruttibile, e lo volgare è non stabile e corruttibile... per
vertù... con ciò sia cosa che lo latino molte cose manifesta concepute
ne la mente che lo volgare far non può... per bellezza perché quello
sermone è più bello ne lo quale più debitamente si rispondono [le
parole; e più debitamente si rispondono] in latino che in volgare: e
per nobilità s'intende la stabilità della convenzione, per vertù la
capacità espressiva, per bellezza l'articolazione della struttura.[grassetto mio]


Può darsi che sia questa la spiegazione. Tuttavia, è quantomeno curioso che Dante usi latino in questo senso proprio nella sua Commedia, di cui lui stesso scriveva nell'Epistola a Cangrande della Scala: «Et per hoc patet, quod comoedia dicitur praesens opus. Nam [...] ad modum loquendi, remissus est modus et humilis, quia loquutio vulgaris, in qua et mulierculae communicant».

Nella traduzione di Angelo Jacomuzzi: «E per ciò è chiaro che la presente opera si dice Commedia. Infatti [...] al modo d'esprimere, è il modo piano e umile, perché lingua volgare in cui discorrono anche le donnette».

Ma infatti Dante è pro-volgare, e promuove un volgare letterario, se vedi nel De Vulgari Eloquentia, scritto per difendere il volgare, dice ad esempio Wikipedia "pur affrontando il tema della lingua volgare, fu scritto in latino in quanto rivolto principalmente ai dotti del tempo per mostrare loro la bellezza della lingua volgare nella loro lingua, appunto il latino." I pensiero di Dante sul volgare è complesso e vario, se vedi anche la voce della Treccani che ho linkato. https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_vulgari_eloquentia

L'aggettivo latino avrà comunque poi preso vita propria, a prescindere dalle varie opinioni di Dante sul volgare nel tempo.

Le parti citate nella risposta sono dal Convivio, poi ci sono altre affermazioni dal Vulgari Eloquentia.

Oltretutto la parola latino nel senso di chiaro non è esclusiva di Dante, l'ho anche ritrovata in espressioni più popolari, anche toscane. Ora non ricordo i link. È possibile che il latino fosse considerato, anche come latino parlato (ho trovato una espressione di un pastore toscano che diceva 'te lo dico latino'), una lingua più uniforme e comprensibile, mentre il volgare, come anche è esaminato nel De Vulgari Eloquentia, è variabile e molto soggetto a varianti regionali.  Non è che lo posso sapere con certezza, ma mi sembra plausibile come spiegazione.

E quanto al tono 'umile' della Commedia, questo è vero in parte, ma lo stile della Commedia è misto, ci sono tutti gli stili,  lo stile basso e lo stile alto, e nel Paradiso, e nell'episodio di Piccarda Donati sembra prevalere lo stile alto.

Aggiungo anch'io una risposta provvisoria, che consiste essenzialmente in una parte della nota a quei versi nell'edizione della Commedia curata da Natalino Sapegno:

[...] le tue parole [...] fanno sì che il ravvisarti mi riesce più agevole. Latino, nel senso di «facile, chiaro» (in quanto espresso nella lingua che ci è più direttamente nota, familiare) si incontra anche in altri scrittori (cfr. G. Villani, Cron., XI, 20), ed era già del latino medievale.


@ Infatti, avevo anche io un'altra risposta, nua uipotesi che è analoga alla tua. C'è un uso accertato nel volgare mediavale dell'uso di latino nel senso di facile, chiaro,ed è probabile che Dante vi si rifacesse. . Pare che questo deruvasse da u alatro significato della parola latino che non ha a che vedre con il latino lingua, ma vuol dire italiano, poiché la parola itaiano allora non esieteva, e quindi parlar latino significava parlare nella lingua madre. L'ho trovato anche in un vecchio dizionario ed in una vecchia edizione commentata della Commedia.

Tuttavia, resto con l'impressione che è difficile  stabilirlo, perché certo Dante prendeva dalla lingua in uso, ma il volgare di Dante non è quello comunemente parlato, e certo non nel Paradiso. Dante ha creato un volgare illustre, come lo chiamava, adatto ad esprimere contenuti letterari 'alti', e la sua lingua è  piena di usi personali e di neologismi.  Il rapporto con il latino per Dante è complesso, non è che l'uso del volgare significasse dismettere o diminuire il latino, come lingua delle chiarezza intellettuale. Basta pensare che tutta la corrispondenza di Dante che abbiamo è in latino.

È vero, non è ovvio, in un verso o nell'altro. Grazie per i commenti, @BakerStreet !

Grazie a te. La tua ipotesi è forse la più plausibile per questo uso attestato, ma per la verità non ho trovato alcun commento di esperti che dicesse con sicurezza 'Dante dice così per questo', tranne nella vecchia edizione che citavo della Commedia (autorevole, comunque) Il fatto è che non si è nella testa di Dante, e il Paradiso è particolare, il volgare usato per descrivere la beatitudine, quindi sicuramente c'è un forte scarto per Dante rispetto lingua comune.
